# BizTalk service and SQL Server

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I recently installed BizTalk Server Dev 2010.
As part of installation, new databases are created and some services are also added.

Because I am currently NOT working with BizTalk Server, I want to stop the service associated with it specially the one that connects to SQL Server.
I have already stopped these three BizTalk services:

```
BizTalk Service BizTalk Group
Enterprise Single Sign-On Service
Rule Engine Update Service
```

but not able to find the one that communicates with BizTalk SQL Server Databases.
I can still see BizTalk SQLs in profiler.

Any idea which other service I should stop?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are also [SQL Server Agent Jobs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919776) created to backup the database and keep the message box and tracking databases running. That is probably what you are seeing activity from.